How to send the access token from collection authorization tab automatically in an environment variables?
I am using the collection authorization tab to generate an access token. Once the token is generated, I would like it to be automatically sent into an environment variable.
I would do the client credential flow in it's own request and post-request script to set variables, but I need to be able to open the browser for autorization since it is a shared library and everybody need to be able to generate its own token:

Ence the reason why I use this. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?
